# Getting .csv data from online "Download .csv" button in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download data from "CSV" button on this page (https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/fireballs/) right to my R application. I saw a couple of similar questions but still can't figure it out. Could anyone help with this? How to find a direct link to a file?

In addition I'd like to scrape "Table Column Descriptions" at the bottom of the page. How to get to this piece of data when I scrape all the page with POST for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (remove the `limit` if you want all data):

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON('https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/fireball.api?limit=100')
dt <- as.data.frame(df$data)
colnames(dt) <- df$fields

head(dt)

                 date energy impact-e  lat lat-dir   lon lon-dir  alt  vel
1 2018-11-20 17:30:28   42.2      1.1 25.3       N   6.7       W 27.4 17.4
2 2018-11-17 21:48:24   22.0     0.61 47.3       N 172.9       W 32.5 19.1
3 2018-11-15 08:02:44    2.0    0.073   42       N    57       W <NA> <NA>
4 2018-11-14 04:03:47    3.8     0.13 37.6       S  83.5       E   37 <NA>
5 2018-10-24 21:19:07    4.7     0.16  6.7       S 148.6       W 33.3 <NA>
6 2018-10-22 07:11:03    2.6    0.092 <NA>    <NA>  <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! As I understand we read the data "thru" api, not thru "download" button, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. download button is for manual but if you want to do it directly, you should use api link.